# How can I copy a list of 500,000 files from windows server 2008 to a seagate NAS?

Tags: windows-server-2008, file-transfer

I have a text file that has ~500,000 full paths. I want to copy them to a NAS once. It's about 1TB of data. Should I make a zip file with all the files or copy them individually?  How can I do either automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a `For` statement command from the command prompt or a batch script

```
For /f %f in (list.txt) do xcopy "%f" \\NasName\dest [switches]
```

Typical switches:

- `/C` Continues copying even if errors occur.
- `/I` If destination does not exist and copying more than one file, assumes that destination must be a directory.
- `/H` Copies hidden and system files also.
- `/R` Overwrites read-only files.
- `/Y` Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an existing destination file.

Do the above command and walk away for a few hours. If the path's are relitive path's in your list file replace `%f` with `C:\path\to\source\%f`

Don't forget you will need privileges to read the file to copy them so if any of your files are in restricted folders (like other users Document's folders) you will need to run the command prompt/batch file as Administrator. Also if you run this in a batch file you will need to replace the single `%` with `%%`

---

If you list of 500,000 files are just all the files under `c:\somepath` you can just use [`Robocopy`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29) instead of `xcopy` + `for` statement

```
robocopy c:\somepath \\NasName\dest [switches]
```

I would recommend the following switches

- `/s` Copies subdirectories. Note that this option excludes empty directories.
- `/zb` Uses Restart mode. If access is denied, this option uses Backup mode.
- `/MT` Creates multi-threaded copies (Works only on Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7)
- `/LOG:<logfile>` Log the results to a file instead of the console (this will boost performance of `/MT`)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I forgot to ask about this so does your solution maintain the directory structure of the paths on the NAS?  And there are spaces in the paths but they are not " wrapped.  Is that addressed in the "%f" part or should I do that before running this script?  Also even though its a 1Gb/s card & switch the NAS seems to be limited to 10MB/s.  IF thats the case would it sway you towards making the zip first? It'll be about 30hrs to transfer

Comment: 1) The `for` does not re-create the directory structure, but `robocopy` does. 2) The `"` in the `"%f"` are wrapping the path's with quotes. 3) 10MB/s is not the greatest transfer speed but it is still decent. You are likely limited by a slow hard drive somewhere 4) If you zip it first, do you plan on leaving it zipped on the nas or how to you plan to un zip it (If you unzip it over the network you are transfering the uncompressed file over the wire anyway during the unzipping process and you are just adding extra time)